# SSH connection with Ruby without username using `authorized_keys`

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, shell, command-line-arguments, net-ssh

I have authenticated a server using `authorized_keys` push so I could run command `ssh 192.168.1.101` from my system and could connect via server.

Now, I tried with library , It didn't worked for me

```
  Net::SSH.start("192.168.1.209",username) do |ssh|   @output=ssh.exec!("ls -l")  end
```

as, This required username field. I want without username.

So , I tried this

```
    system('ssh 192.168.1.209 "ls -l"')
```

It run the command for me. But I want the output in a variable like `@output` in first example. Is there any command any gem or any way by which I could get the solution ?

Comment: also, I would need to run 5-10 commands in a request..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass parameters into %x[] as follows:

```
1. dom = ‘www.ruby-rails.in‘
2. @whois = %x[whois #\{dom\}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Any ssh connection requires a username. The default is either your system account name or whatever's specified in `.ssh/config` for that host you're connecting to.

Your current username should be set as `ENV['USER']` if you need to access that.

If you're curious what username is being used for that connection, try finding out with `ssh -v` which is the verbose mode that explains what's going on.

Comment: actually in shell prompt, I am able to run `ssh 192.168.1.209` it connect without asking username because I copied keys and added into authorized_keys .

Comment: The username is always required even with the authorized keys, because the key doesn't necessarily tell the server which user is logging in.  Likely that `ssh` is getting your username from the OS or config file

Comment: Exactly, you can connect without it *asking* for a username, but that doesn't mean it isn't *using* a username

Answer (score 0):

Backquotes works very similar to "system" function but with important difference. Shell command enclosed between the backquotes is executed with standard output as result.

So, following statement should execute ssh 192.168.1.209 "ls -l" and puts directory files listing into @output variable:

```
@output = `ssh 192.168.1.209 "ls -l"`
```